# Django ModelAdmin saving database field

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm trying to use a modelForm within a modelAdmin to change a DB field. IteAdmin is copied from [mezzanine's blog admin](http://mezzanine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/mezzanine/blog/admin.html)

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    send_email = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def email(self, model, commit=True):
        send_email = self.cleaned_data.get('send_email', None)
        content = self.cleaned_data.get('content', None)
        if send_email == True:
            mod = Ite.objects.get(id=self.instance.id)
            print mod.email_recipients #>'NOT SENT'
            mod.email_recipients = 'EMAIL SENT'
            mod.save() # this does nothing
            print mod.email_recipients #> 'EMAIL SENT'
        return super(YourModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)


class IteAdmin(TweetableAdminMixin, DisplayableAdmin, OwnableAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = YourModelForm
    def save_form(self, request, forms, change):
        OwnableAdmin.save_form(self, request, forms, change)
        DisplayableAdmin.save_form(self, request, forms, change)
        return YourModelForm.email(forms,self)
```

I think the value 'EMAIL SENT' is being overwritten by the other saves? I'm completely new to modeladmins and really struggling.
Basically i want to send an email if the checkbox is checked, then update the model (Ite) so it's shows that an email has been sent. It's been recommended that i use signals to achieve the emailing part which i will do but i need to figure out how to update the model first. Any help massively appreciated

Comment: Wrap the mod.save() with a `try... except`, see if the save fails.

Comment: thanks, yeh it is saving. looks like it saves but then is overwritten again?

Comment: As an aside, why have you written `IteAdmin` in this way? If there's nothing I'm missing, look into `super()` to clean up your code a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

1. You shouldn't be calling `super().save()` from anything other than your class's `save()` method.
2. Your solution to sending email (a field on the model that a receiver will later check) is pretty hacky. I'd try another route if possible. For example:

Stop unnecessarily messing with your model in your `ModelForm`'s `save()`. In fact, take that 'email sent' field out altogether. Write an `email()` method on the form that actually sends the email. Then you can just call that method whenever you want to send the email. If you want it to happen automatically, override your form's `save()` and (after using `super()` to let `ModelForm` do its thing) call `email()` if the user has ticked the `send_email` field.

Comment: Spent too long on this and lost clarity. In the process of adding an action button to the change_form to deal with the email. and yeh i realized i shouldn't be returning super (left over code from hours of failure..) Thanks

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)